# Possibility of implementing Open Graph without website where metadata is stored, Can Open Graph Metadata be dynamically injected into a URL?

Tags: android, ios, facebook-opengraph

This is a broad questions and I'm merely looking for source material that may be of help with this unique situation.

Background: Mobile app that can share data it's data to other websites and other mobile apps. This mobile app is ONLY for mobile, not for web in any way. This means there's no front facing website to view items that one would view in the app. The server, however, is residing on the web and does have URLs for image assets, etc.

Problem: I'm trying to sort out a way to share items from this mobile app to services like Twitter and Facebook, Notes inside the mobile device iOS device, etc, but instead of attaching image/video data raw. I'd like to be able to send Open Graph Metadata when sharing so that the item is shown like a normal Open Graph card would appear on these other websites and apps. I want it to look true to open graph, but when said item is clicked, I want it to take the user to either open my app with a deep link to the item or open the App landing page to download the app.

I've found zero information on making open graph work this way so that rich cards appear in websites without needing the website like twitter and facebook to crawl back to my site and pull the metadata based on a URL.

Any experience with making this work would helpful. I'm not looking for a coded example here, I'm looking for documentation on this unique circumstance and implementation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are three options that I can see.

1. You permanently host the metadata on your site.  `example.com/?id=1234` is a basic HTML page which just has that metadata when a crawler hits it.
2. You dynamically host the metadata on your site. `example.com/?img=whatever.jpg&title=some%20text` generates the metadata when it is crawled.
3. The app host the website. A user shares `https://1234.example.com/?id=5678` - your DNS resolves to their phone. Their app is running a web server which returns the metadata.

You cannot get away with needing *something* to serve a small amount of HTML + metadata.

Given users without the app will visit your website - you might as well put the Schema stuff there.